# how to lock a draggable route with google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got google map on my webapp working with the JavaScript API V3. I give my users the ability to create some routes with this features:

1. the user can create a route.
2. the user can add waypoints doing click on the map.
3. the use can modify any waypoint and the markers origin/destination dragging the marker on the map.
4. the user can save the route.

**The problem:**

If the user click and dragging some part of the route without use any waypoint, the route change but I can't save it. Because I save the markers origin/destination and the waypoints.

there is any way to lock the route?

1. [Here you can see an example in API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable)

Below I leave an image that you can see how the user drag the black and white circle and change the route (this is that I try to lock).

[image]

Comment: I have tried to move the circle in example code on link and it works as expected to change route. Maybe you can explain a bit more about issue and what you mean by lock?

Comment: If users drag the route using black and white you should add it as a new waypoint and then user can delete or move it to adjust. Dont allow user to create temporary viewpoint which that black and white circle is doing.

Comment: this is the problem, if you move the circle the route change. I don't want the user can change the route using the circle. I want the user only use the markers for  change the route. Why? because I can't save all the point in the route. I only save markers origin/destination and waypoints. I hope I explained

Answer (score 0):

You need to tap into direction_changed event listener and puckup route points and see which ones you need and which ones you dont.

The other solution is to use non draggable route code and only allow user to click and create a point. Then calculate dustance when you have more than 1 points. Allow user to drag marker only and update route and total distance on drop marker.

If you can create a jsfiddle of what you have done so far it would help us look into it and give you a more accurate answer with working example.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem today and found out that there's a setting for it. You just need to set the `clickable` property of `polylineOptions`  to `false`.

```
this.directionsRenderer=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({draggable:!0,map,panel:this.elements.directionsBody,polylineOptions:{clickable:!1,strokeColor:"#4BAFF8"}})
```

DirectionsRenderer:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRendererOptions.polylineOptions

PolylineOptions: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#PolylineOptions